# Spring Security SAML - Cannot catch UserNameNotFound Exception

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-saml

I've throw UserNameNotFound Exception in my SAMLUserDetailsService. But it still call my AuthenticationSuccessHandler when user is not in DB.

Do you have any idea on this issue?
This is a part of my loadUserBySAML method

```
            String userName = nameValue.trim();
            AppUser domainUser = userRepository.findByAppUserNm(userName);

            if (domainUser == null) {
                logger.info("User is null");

                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User is not in the DB");

            } else {
                boolean enabled = true;
                boolean accountNonExpired = true;
                boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
                boolean accountNonLocked = true;

                return new User(domainUser.getAppUserNm(), domainUser.getAppUserPwdTxt().toLowerCase(), enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired,
                        accountNonLocked, getAuthorities(userName));
            }
```

Comment: can you share your spring-saml-security.xml file?
did you check whether domainUser is null

Comment: Yes, I did it. "User is null" be written in log. I saw that it always return SUCCESS in ProcessingFilter.

I implemented the authenticationSuccessHandler & authenticationFailedHandler. 
This is my config in security file.
<bean id="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailure"/>
    </bean>

Comment: Check if you are passing your SAMLUserDetailsService implementer class properly in samlUserDetailsService bean.

Comment: I'll see if I can get the issue reproduced. Having your complete configuration would be helpful.